# Reference needed: Donsker's Invariance Principle for Riemannian Manifolds

Tags: brownian-motion, reference-request

After an extensive unsuccessful search: I need a reference (preferably a book) for the Donsker's invariance principle for Riemannian manifolds. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generalization of Donsker's theorem from $N$-dimensional Euclidean space to general Riemannian manifolds has been worked out by Erik Jørgensen, [The Central Limit Problem for Geodesic Random Walks](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2FBF00533088).

> The purpose of the present work is to
>   consider the problem of defining the
>   concept of a random walk in a general
>   Riemannian manifold ${\cal M}$, and to
>   investigate the behavior in the limit
>   of a sequence of such random walks. It
>   will be shown that such a sequence,
>   under reasonable assumptions,
>   converges to a diffusion process in
>   ${\cal M}$, and in particular Brownian motion
>   processes will be obtained as limits
>   of sequences of random walks with
>   identically distributed steps. The
>   results which we arrive at in this
>   paper are general versions of
>   well-known classical results
>   concerning the transition from random
>   walks to diffusion processes, for
>   instance: the central limit theorem
>   and Donsker's theorem.

Comment: @Carlo So far it looks very promising - and provides pretty much interesting reading material ... Thanks a lot!

@Stephan Thank you very much for your helping hand.

Comment: yes, thank you Stephan for your expert advise.

Answer (score 0):

D. Khoshnevisan, Lecture notes on Donsker's theorem

http://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/donsker.pdf

Comment: Great lecture notes on Donsker's theorem in $\mathbb{R}$. However, I do not see how this could be applied to a generic manifold setting.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably interested by the paper

*Empirical invariance principle for ergodic torus automorphisms*; Genericity. Olivier Durieu, Philippe Jouan. Stochastics and Dynamics, volume 8, 2, p. 173-195, 2008.

It is available [here](http://www.lmpt.univ-tours.fr/~durieu/).