# random walk and Brownian motion on Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, riemannian-geometry, random-walks, brownian-motion

As we know, the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}/n$ will converge(in some sense) to the Brownian motion on $\mathbb{R}$ when $n\to\infty$. I would like to know is there some higher dimensional analogy result.

**Edit:** As pointed by Nate Eldredge, there is a generalization of Donsker's theorem on manifold. But, I am interested in the following more topological  generalization.

For a compact Riemannian manifold $X$, if a triangulation is given. Is there a canoncal way to defined a random walk $W$ on the vertex of the triangulation, such that $W^n$ the random walk defined in this way after $n$-th barycentric subdivision will converge to the Brownian motion on $X$.

Comment: See [Reference needed: Donsker's Invariance Principle for Riemannian Manifolds](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126368/reference-needed-donskers-invariance-principle-for-riemannian-manifolds); I think the references given there should answer your question.  I'm tentatively marking this as duplicate.

Comment: hi, Nate Eldredge. I am afraid Donsker's theorem is nothing to do with the triangulation.

Comment: Hi shu, Since Nate has marked this as a possible duplicate, perhaps you might expand your question to clarify why Donsker's theorem doesn't do what you want?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want out of the construction you propose.  Certainly it depends on the triangulation, whereas Brownian motion doesn't, right?

Comment: @Noah Stein, but the limit process might be a universal objet...

Comment: The limit process is not universal.  Consider triangulating a circle by slicing the top half into $M$ segments and the bottom into just one.  Then the scale of the motion in the top half will be $1/M$ times the scale of the motion in the bottom half at every iteration, so also in any reasonable limit.

Comment: What I mean by random walk is not to say at each point, we take 1/2 chance to one of the other next points. In the case you metioned, we shoud take account of length of the edge to modifier the proba to the next point.

Comment: In fact, in the case if we take account of length of each edge, the triangulation will converge as metric space to the manifold $X$. So if we can define a random walk(which take  account of length of the edge), the limit should be universal.

Comment: This comes down to discrete approximation of a continuous diffusion. You will be guaranteed weak convergence as long as the generator of the discrete process approximates the generator of BM on the manifold (i.e., the Laplacian) closely enough.

Comment: @GeorgeLowther, yes, this is exact what I would like to do! But not so evident...

Answer (score 7):

Nicolas Th. Varopoulos, [Brownian motion and random walks on manifolds](http://aif.cedram.org/item?id=AIF_1984__34_2_243_0), Annales de l'Institut Fourier 34(2) (1984), 243-269.

Abstract: *We develop a procedure that allows us to “discretise” the Brownian motion on a Riemannian manifold. We construct thus a random walk that is a good approximation of the Brownian motion.*

Comment: Hi, Did. I just read the introduction. But it seems no convergence result in that paper. If I undersand correctly, they get a good approximation. And using this approximation to get some estimation on the heat kernel.

Comment: I guess "good approximation" means that an error of some sort goes to zero when the mesh of the discretization goes to zero?